# C++ Better for Performance than C?

Tags: c++, c, performance, generics, constants

I'm currently working on some high-performance, stability-critical frameworks, which will likely deploy on x86_64, ia64, and potentially ARM platforms. The library is so far done in C. The current standard is C99, though we are interested in experimenting with features of C11.

Initially, the choice to avoid C++ was because we wanted to prevent developers from using classes due to their inherent inefficiencies, such as larger memory footprints, vtables, and inheritance. We also wanted to keep structs free of member functions. In other words, C was chosen over C++ deliberately to prevent to use of certain features in C++.

However, we recently did a double-take after further investigating some of C++'s features. It certainly seems to have some benefits, mainly type safety and generics.

What I would like to know is:

1- What, exactly, does this type-safety mean for the programmer and compiler?

2- What are the benefits of C++'s type safety, and how can we avoid the pitfalls of unsafe typing with C?

Comment: IMHO you should split this up into several SO questions.

Comment: Okay, I'll remove the parts about generics. Thanks!

Comment: For generics, you could also take a look at google, e.g. [this blog seems quite nice](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html) :D

Comment: #1 question for you: How many true C++ programmers do you have?  I don't mean C programmers that use classes, but people who Know C++ in and out?  If the answer is "not enough", then stick with C.  All the other stuff is fine, but an inexperienced C++ programmer will negate any gains that "might" come from C++ coding.

Comment: Here's [Bjarne Stroustrup's opinion](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#C-is-better) about C. Of course, it isn't biased :P

Comment: Some resources related to C++ performance, unfortunately a bit out-dated: [Technical Report on C++ performance from 2006](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/TR18015.pdf), further links [on the TR homepage](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/18015.html)

Comment: Your question is clear and well-formed, but I'm not sure this is the right forum for it.  A *good* answer to your questions could easily fill a book chapter.

Comment: @DrewDormann IMO one could answer 1) and 2) w/o the performance aspect, they should even be duplicates.

Comment: Pick the language your programmers know. The real code they write in their native language will be far better than the ideal code that an experienced programmer might possibly write in that language.

Comment: @jepugs It sounds like you're aware that there are pitfalls of unsafe typing in C.  Are you?  Can you show what you know?

Comment: @Drew Dormann Perhaps I should have added that to the question. I'm actually a bit unclear on the specific damages that can be caused by unsafe typing, though I am aware that they often result in buffer or stack vulnerabilities.

Comment: @jepugs Would you consider removing your unrelated question 3?  It looks like some people might consider taking a stab at the first two.  You could also post question 3 as a new question.

Comment: @DrewDormann Good idea, I've done it.

Comment: @DyP: Counter argument: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus

Comment: @EdS. I don't think a fact-less rant qualifies as a counter argument to anything other than another rant, but I do find that e-mail quite entertaining.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is certainly a counter argument to *"Not in my opinion. I never saw a project for which C was better than C++ for any reason but the lack of a good C++ compiler."*.  I happen to agree with much of what he said.  C++ does a lot of things I like, but damn if that good stuff doesn't come with a crap-ton of complexity and baggage.

Comment: @EdS. Of course there's some truth to what Linus says. If you don't take care and don't think about what you're doing - like using exceptions in the kernel or "hidden" dynamic memory allocation, or excessive use of virtual functions. If C++ programmers tend to use those features - make _sure_ they don't do it here. Also, we're not talking about a kernel here I assume, and as many other have already stated, it is very important your programmers know the language well (for both C and C++).

Comment: @EdS. well, it is a bit hard when people are talking about what they have seen. I still believe C++ provides a programmer with tools to organize code better, and giving more information to the compiler provides scope for more compile time optimization and/or error checking. I think a lot of misgivings about C++ are down to a scarcity of conforming compilers, but that situation is much better now than it was even seven years ago or so. That said, I have to deal with tons of awfully written C++ every day and I can see how the complexity of the language can be counterproductive in the wrong hands

Comment: Take a look at type-based alias analysis, http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/type-based-alias-analysis/184404273

Answer (score 1):

1- What, exactly, does this type-safety mean for the programmer and compiler?

Type safety protects you from debugging silly mistakes, such as Adding Degrees and Radians together or trying to multiply a "string" to an integer. I wouldn't worry about the effects on the compiler. Having programmed in both type-safe languages (C++) and Non-typesafe (PERL,C) I would say that I normally spend less time debugging "Computer internal" things in the type-safe languages (again, adding strings and integers) but spend more time chasing type values and definitions and converting between them.

2- What are the benefits of C++'s type safety, and how can we avoid the pitfalls of unsafe typing with C?

The Type safety is a level of protection that allows the compiler to check that what you are doing is sane. For an individual this is less important than in a group setting because while you know that your "GetNumberOfStudents" function outputs a string instead of an integer, your co-workers may not. The bigger advantage of C++ over C is that you can separate the way you store your data from the way you retrieve your data, so that "GetListOfAllCustomers" won't change to the people using the function if you decide to internally change your data structures.

Short answer: If you're willing to trade developer time and hardware comprehension time for performance and compactness, I would lean towards C. If you're willing to trade a small amount of performance and aren't memory bound, to lessen developer time, I would lean towards C++. I program in C# for all my data analysis and C for all my embedded software work.

Answer (score 0):

Templates in C++ can make it practical to write code that yields better performance than the same code in C. For example, you can do things like generate unrolled loops tuned at compile time to match your problem size coherently to your target's cache size.

Pointer arithmetic and casts in C can potentially lead to buffer over-runs, dangling references and memory leaks. C++ features like smart pointers and container classes can greatly reduce the incidence of these kinds of bugs.

Powerful idioms like RAII are directly supported by C++ language features, and make it much easier to do things like write multi-threaded concurrency correctly without introducing race conditions or deadlocks.

Rich types that represent critical data attributes like unit values and dimensions enable the compiler to catch unit conversion errors at compile time. It is possible to do checked conversions with structs and typedefs in C, but a typical C implementation would catch many unit errors only at run time, if at all, whereas a C++ implementation can be both safer and faster than the equivalent functionality written in C.

These are just some simple examples, but there is much, much more to say about the pitfalls and limitations of C, and the ways that C++ language features may be used to write code that is fast, correct and resilient to change.

Comment: Since we're programming a system-level library, we're avoiding libraries like STL and Boost like the plague. In fact, our aim is to have literally no dependencies except for libc. Template metaprogramming can have some interesting effects on C++ performance, but can also generate strange and platform-specific errors, and unreadable code, so we would like not to use it in a project where stability is so important.